# Explanation why a set in $(\Bbb R^2)^n$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be the set of points in $(\Bbb R^2)^n$ that describe the vertices of a polygon $Q$ (may self-intersect) with fixed perimeter $P$ such that one vertex is $(0;0)$

I read that $X$ will be compact, but I can't seem to logically see why. I believe it may be due to the fact that all vertices of polygon $Q$ are within a certain distance from the origin due to the fixed perimeter of $Q$. But to me, this would not make $X$ bounded, since if all vertices are of the form $(x;y)$, we would have $x^2 + y^2\lt (\frac{P}{2})^2$, which would not make the vertices closed. Can someone please explain why this is true.

Comment: Any finite collection of points in Euclidean space is a compact set.

Comment: @CameronWilliams This is not the question.

Comment: @Scuffednewton I am not sure to understand your problem : $x^2+y^2 < (P/2)^2$ makes the vertices bounded, since it implies $|x| < P/2$ and $|y| < P/2$...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe It should effectively be though, since a polygon has finitely many vertices. The set is bounded for fairly trivial reasons and closed also for fairly trivial reasons.

Comment: @CameronWilliams We are not considering the set of vertices of one polygon, but the set of all the possible collections of vertices of a $n-$polygon with perimeter equal to $P$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe, as far as my limited knowledge of mathematics goes, I believed a bounded set included its endpoints? So I thought that fact would only make it closed?

Comment: Should the question then read "Let $X$ be the set of all possible points..."?

Comment: @ScuffedNewton It seems that you make a confusion between bounded and closed. Bounded means that there exists $M$ such that all the coordinates have absolute value less that $M$... So it is the case here.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Do you make a difference between "The set of points such that..." and "The set of all possible points such that"  ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Yes. Because the way the post is phrased, it sounds like a fixed polygon vs a set of all possibly polygons (and their possible vertices).

Comment: @TheSilverDoe, I apologise for my ignorance. So is my reasoning enough to prove it is compact?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Well, it is mentionned that $X$ is a subset of $(\mathbb{R}^2)^n$, and not of $\mathbb{R}^2$...

Comment: @ScuffedNewton You proved it's bounded. To prove it's compact (in $(\mathbb{R}^2)^n$) you still need to show it's closed.

Comment: @ScuffedNewton There are many (equivalent) definitions of what it means for a set to be closed, most likely in your case a set is closed if it contains its limit points.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, $X$ will only be closed if you include degenerate polygons, but then your proof of boundedness is not quite right (it should be $\leq (P/2)^2$ rather than $< (P/2)^2$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This set is
$$X=\left\{ (x_1,  \dots , x_n) \in ( \Bbb R^2)^n  : x_1 = (0,0) ,  \left( \sum_{i=2}^n ||x_i-x_{i-1}||_2 \right) + ||x_n-x_1||_2 =P \right\}$$
where $$||x||_2$$ denotes the usual euclidean norm of a vector $x$.

Since the Euclidean norm is continuous, this set is clearly closed.

For boundedness you can trivially bound
$$0 \le ||x_1||_2, \dots , ||x_n||_2 \le P$$
in other words your set is a subset of $$X \subseteq (B(0,P))^n$$ which is clearly bounded.

Comment: I have a question. You have said x1 = (0;0) but isn’t x1 an element of R^2N, not R^2?

Comment: I write $x_1=(0,0)$ because of the requirement that one of the vertices of the polygon $Q$ has to be $(0,0)$.

Comment: Just to confirm, $X={(x1,…,xn)∈(R2)n:x1=(0,0),(∑i=2n||xi−xi−1||2)+||xn−x1||2=P}$ means that the inverse image of P under continuous function $(∑i=2n||xi−xi−1||2)+||xn−x1||2$ is X, and since P is closed, X is closed.

Comment: @ScuffedNewton This is exactly what I meant.